# How can I add additional connector (glue) points to a shape in word or powerpoint?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-powerpoint, shapes, flowchart

How can I add additional connector points to a shape in word or powerpoint?

In openoffice draw these are called glue points.

What I want in ms powerpoint:

[image]

What I can do in open office draw:

[image]

UPDATE: Based on Steve Rindsberg's answer I did this: Draw a rectangle, then a second one. Make the second rectangle very small and move it over, then behind the first rectangle. Then group them. I guess this is actually a functioning workaround for my question, even though it is not what I wanted to hear. Accepting the answer...

[image]

Answer (score 47, accepted):

From PowerPoint 2013 onwards, you can do the following:

- Right-click the border of a shape
- Choose *Edit Points*
- Ctrl-click to add a point, or right-click and select *Add Point*

These become glue points that connector lines and such will snap to. Note that this changes the original shape and may break connections to existing glue points.

With older versions, you can't add more glue points, but you can draw an additional shape with glue points where you want them, then group it with the first shape.

Comment: At least in PPT 2013 you can right-click on a shape and Edit Points, then add new points with CTRL-click. But it can be a nice approach to combine the Edit Points on a shape that's then invisible and grouped behind your original shape. Adding new points also changes the shape lines themselves rather than just adding new anchor points, so grouping with your original might make it easier to just add anchor points without altering the look of the original.

Comment: Yes, you can add more points.  But right-click the border of the shape.  And I found in PPT 2016 that if you add a point after shape is connected to other shapes, PPT insanely redraws the slides connections into a big mess, like a spider on LSD.

Comment: Following up:  Whether this has changed since {whatever_version_I_tested_with} or what, you're correct. Adding more points using Edit Points does create more glue points (but it can also make the original glue points cease to function, oddly ... add a new point to one side of a rectangle and the original point in the center of the side departs this life, and any connected lines jump to one of the corners rather than to the newly added point, which seems a bit odd). Thanks @Rory (and Doug but SO won't let me point @ you too)

Comment: The edit (and other answers) is correct: you can use Edit Points.  However, in my experience the results can be very ugly.  Creating and invisible, grouped shape is more work, but allows much better control over the appearance.

Comment: But these points change the shape of the original form.

Comment: @Alexis_FR_JP Yes, they can. See the rest of the comments for other options.

Comment: Well, this new feature (edit shape points) seems to be so cool, except that the shape will become totally messed up if you add two or more extra points. The lines will be bent and not sure how to add more points on a side of a rectangle for example without bending the line in a weird way.

Comment: I played with this a bit and see what you mean. In some cases, setting the nearest pre-existing corner point to be a corner point (yep, tell it to be what PPT is already telling you that it is) can help. Bug, I'd say. In other cases, adding another point directly atop an previously added point's control handle can cause the shape to go mildly crazy, so avoid doing that.

Comment: Edit Points in PowerPoint version 2106 is still hideous.  Adding a point distorts your shape, and glueing a right-angle connector to one goes off parallel to the line rather than perpendicular.  Totally unusable.  However, the idea of creating other shapes under your main one with connectors just where you want them is inspired brilliance, and gets my vote!

Answer (score 9):

This description can be found at [this link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/word-help/draw-or-delete-a-line-connector-or-freeform-shape-HA010355850.aspx):

[image: Edit points in a shape]

Comment: But Edit Points deforms the shape

Comment: In Word, when I add edit points, the shape is messed up. Also, when I fix the connector elbows then as soon as I touch the shape, it will be rerouted in a funny way.

Answer (score 4):

I had same issue and was annoyed with adding points method because of need to be very careful for spline interpolation between points (was really hard to make straight line and align points very carefully). So here is what I did:

**[Step1]**

Start to draw a rectangle with two smaller rectangles in it (add lines connected to smaller rectangles to get the big picture)

[image: step1]

**[Step2]**

Resize smaller rectangles to snap on edges of the bigger one

[image: step2]

[Step3]

Select no to draw contour for smaller rectangles (at this point I also removed helper lines)

[image: step3]

**[Step4]**

Group the rectangles in a single form

[image: step4]

**[Step5]**

Add this new form to your favorites

[image: step5]

**[And voilà]**

You can now connect lines at added new points

[image: voila]

Comment: additional tipp: before grouping, send the outer rectangle to back

Answer (score 2):

The above method only works in newer versions of PPT and it doesn't work with curved shapes. If you try to add a connection or glue point to a curved shape it distorts the shape.

Here is a workaround for earlier versions of PPT and for curved shapes.

1. Add a shape, any shape.
2. Then away from the first shape add a circle shape and shrink it down as small as you can make it - you can use the Size tool to make it say 0.1cm - so that it is just a dot.
3. To start with make sure the fill colour of the dot is different from the shape at point '1'.
4. Amend the line (outline) colour of the dot so that it has no colour.
5. Duplicate the dot a few times - sufficient for the number of connection points you want to add to the shape at '1'. They will become your new connection points.
6. Then position the dots just inside the outer edge of the shape at '1' exactly where you want them to be.
7. When you've done this and you're sure they're exactly where they should be, change the fil colour of all the dots to the same as the main shape at '1'. So that you can no longer see them.
8. Now select and group the main shape at '1' and all the dots inside it together.
9. Finally add another shape, then a connector, and try connecting it to the main shape at the the postion where you've added one of your dots.

   If this has worked both ends of the connector should be green, thus proving your dots are now acting as connection points.
10. If you're using a gradient fill for the main shape then the points will still be visible.

    However if at point 8 where you group them altogether, you bring the main shape to the front thus masking the dots, it will still work.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer at [Phlogtastic](http://phlogtastic.blogspot.com/2012/07/powerpoint-add-connection-point-to.html) via [Indezine](https://www.indezine.com/products/powerpoint/learn/shapes/creating-connector-anchorpoints-ppt2010.html)

It is kind of convoluted but seems to work mostly in PP 2013:

Step 1 - Right click the shape
Step 2 - Choose **Edit-Points**
Step 3 - Left-click where you want the new point (cursor changes to a combo square-crosshair)

[image]

Step 4 - Right-click at the same position without moving mouse and select **Add Point**.

[image]

In some cases when I tried to do this on a rectangle it made that edge of the rectangle curved.  But re-creating the rectangle from scratch made it work ok.

Answer (score 1):

The "Add Point" super sucks, never use it.
Just:

1. create a tiny circle.
2. Bring it to the front.
3. adjust its transparancy to 90%.
4. group two shapes together.

[image: #3]

[image: #4]

Answer (score -2):

I figured PowerPoint 2013 does not allow to edit the "arrow connector" shape's points.  Creating a "curve" lets me edit the points of the curve.