# How do I edit points of a shape in PowerPoint 2016?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-office-2016

In PowerPoint 2016 (the preview version), you can edit points in a shape by right-clicking and selecting *Edit Points*.

Now, [under Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/628583/how-can-i-add-additional-connector-glue-points-to-a-shape-in-word-or-powerpoin), you would add a point by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-clicking, or change its connection type by <kbd>Alt</kbd>-clicking. But under OS X, neither of those shortcuts achieves anything. Clicking reverts back to the normal mode.

[image]

What should be used instead?

Comment: I'd use Office 2011 instead.  It works there pretty much as it does under Windows.  Office 2016 is a public preview, not a tested release.  It's *guaranteed* to be bug-ridden.